# odbc_exec() error when inserting something into the database

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I have a problem with a function which normally has to insert an entry into the database.
I am using SQL Server 2000 ( my entreprise environment ) with odbc.
My scripting langage is PHP.
By the way, I've done an `echo $insertQuery` which prints the content of the query when it's executed and the login, is not shown.

**Warning: odbc_execute() [function.odbc-execute]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]'Users' : nom d'objet incorrect., SQL state S0002 in SQLExecute in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www\SMGAB\includes\fonctions.php on line 97**

And the function :

```
function addUser() {
   $bdd = connexionBD() ;

   // Variables declaration 
   $userLoginToAdd  = $_POST['userLoginAdd']; 
   $userNameToAdd   = $_POST['userNameAdd'];
   $userEmailToAdd  = $_POST['userEmailAdd'];
   $userProfilType  = $_POST['userProfileType'];

   // Replace the "Administrator" and "User" by 1 and 2. 
   if ( $userProfilType == "Administrateur" ) {
    $profilByID = 1;
   }
   else if ( $userProfilType == "Utilisateur" ) {
       $profilByID = 2;
   }

   // Insère dans la base de donnée 

   $addUser = "INSERT INTO
                  Users('login','email','identity','type_profil')
               VALUES (                          
                    '".$userLoginToAdd."',
                    '".$userEmailToAdd."',
                    '".$userNameToAdd."',
                    ".$profilByID."
               )" ; 

   $query = odbc_exec( $bdd, $addUser ) ;
}
```

Comment: The query itself seems to fail, are you sure that a table named "Users" exists? [This page (*click*)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqlgetstarted/thread/16b82d6c-86ce-4f26-84aa-05772679d540) says that you need to specify the full identifier: `ServerName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName`

Comment: Yes, what seems weird is the fact thar i've already used a query on this table in order to look if a login exists. and it works well.

Comment: My problem got resolved ! i've deleted the part between the table Users and the VALUES keyword and it works well. Thanks :)